# Invocation of a Huggingface Summarization Model using AWS Servereless Sagemaker Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, artificial-intelligence, amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model, huggingface

I am trying to run an AWS Serverless SageMaker Endpoint with the `huggingface-summarization-bert-small2bert-small-finetuned-cnn-daily-mail-summarization` model for simple text summarization.

This is my AWS CloudFormation template:

```
SageMakerModel:
  Type: AWS::SageMaker::Model
  Properties:
    ModelName: SummarizationModel
    Containers:
      - Image: "763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-inference:1.13.1-transformers4.26.0-cpu-py39-ubuntu20.04"
        ModelDataUrl: "s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-1/huggingface-infer/infer-huggingface-summarization-bert-small2bert-small-finetuned-cnn-daily-mail-summarization.tar.gz"
        Mode: SingleModel
    ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt SageMakerExecutionRole.Arn


SageMakerEndpointConfig:
  Type: "AWS::SageMaker::EndpointConfig"
  Properties:
    ProductionVariants:
      - ModelName: !GetAtt SageMakerModel.ModelName
        VariantName: "ServerlessVariant"
        ServerlessConfig: 
          MaxConcurrency: 1
          MemorySizeInMB: 2048

SageMakerEndpoint:
  Type: "AWS::SageMaker::Endpoint"
  Properties:
    EndpointName: SummarizationEndpoint
    EndpointConfigName:
      !GetAtt SageMakerEndpointConfig.EndpointConfigName
```

The model is deployed successfully as far as I can tell.

I have deployed a Python lambda function to invoke the endpoint. This is my code:

```
client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
payload = {
  'inputs': 'Summarize this text: This is a beautiful day. I am happy. I am going to the park.'
}

response = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName="SummarizationEndpoint", 
        ContentType="application/json", 
        Accept="application/json",
        Body=json.dumps(payload)
        # Body=bytes(json.dumps(payload), 'utf-8') # alternative attempt - not working
        # Body=json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8") # alternative attempt - not working
    )
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
An error occurred: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: 
Received client error (400) from model with message "
{ 
  "code": 400, 
  "type": "InternalServerException", 
   "message": "\u0027str\u0027 object is not callable"
}".
```

Since this is a `ModelError` I am assuming the model is deployed and the inference pipeline is being called. I am unsure about the payload format though.
Judging from the test code [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-huggingface-inference-toolkit/blob/main/tests/integ/config.py) I am guessing that the text-to-be-summarized should be passed in the `inputs` property of the payload like it is being done [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-huggingface-inference-toolkit/blob/80634b30703e8e9525db8b7128b05f713f42f9dc/tests/integ/config.py#L84).
Looking at the `SummarizationPipeline` though, I don't quite understand the comments [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/818997788584b9fc043d8b58e078f63aadb6b60e/src/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py#L250) - should there be a `documents` property somewhere? I played with all possible combinations of `inputs`, `documents`, etc but without success.

What is the correct way to pass the payload to the model? Can I see a working example?

**Update 1**: These are the logs from CloudWatch when I use the version `payload = {'inputs':'...'}`:

```
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 1084, in __call__
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Prediction error
[INFO ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend response time: 3
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Traceback (most recent call last):
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit/handler_service.py", line 234, in handle
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     response = self.transform_fn(self.model, input_data, content_type, accept)
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit/handler_service.py", line 190, in transform_fn
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     predictions = self.predict(processed_data, model)
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit/handler_service.py", line 158, in predict
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     prediction = model(inputs)
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py", line 165, in __call__
[INFO ] W-9000-model ACCESS_LOG - /127.0.0.1:48184 "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 400 3416
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     result = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 1084, in __call__
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     return self.run_single(inputs, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params)
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 1090, in run_single
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     model_inputs = self.preprocess(inputs, **preprocess_params)
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py", line 175, in preprocess
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     inputs = self._parse_and_tokenize(inputs, truncation=truncation, **kwargs)
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py", line 130, in _parse_and_tokenize
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     inputs = self.tokenizer(*args, padding=padding, truncation=truncation, return_tensors=self.framework)
[INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I looked into the code of `handler_service.py`. As the line 158 is executed, it means this payload successfully passes line 151

```
        inputs = data.pop("inputs", data)
```

... which confirms that `inputs` must be the property name.

However, looking further into the stacktrace I couldn't find anything interesting. The inputs are being passed to the [`tokenizer`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/820c46a707ddd033975bc3b0549eea200e64c7da/src/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py#L130) and this is where my stacktrace ends.

**Update 2**: I noticed that the same invocation code works with another model. Here's the model yaml that does work:

```
SageMakerModel2:
  Type: AWS::SageMaker::Model
  Properties:
    ModelName: SummarizationModel2
    Containers:
      - Image: "763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-inference:1.7.1-transformers4.6.1-cpu-py36-ubuntu18.04"
        ModelDataUrl: "s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-1/huggingface-infer/infer-huggingface-translation-t5-small.tar.gz"
        Mode: SingleModel
    ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt SageMakerExecutionRole.Arn
```

After further analysis I learned that the multi-model-server calls `handler_service.initialize` when loading the model to create a pipeline using the `pipeline()` function.

I then downloaded both models and tried to instantiate a pipeline on my machine from both models to see what happens to the tokenizer. Here is the code...

```
# p1 model is not working
p1 = pipeline("summarization", "/REDACTED/Code/infer-huggingface-summarization-bert-small2bert-small-finetuned-cnn-daily-mail-summarization")

# p2 model is working
p2 = pipeline("text2text-generation", "/REDACTED/Code/infer-huggingface-translation-t5-small/")
print("Tokenizer for P1: " + str(type(p1.tokenizer)))
print("Tokenizer for P2: " + str(type(p2.tokenizer)))
```

The code proves that `p1.tokenizer` is of `NoneType` whereas `p2.tokenizer` is of class `'transformers.models.t5.tokenization_t5_fast.T5TokenizerFast'`.

After further investigating the code of `pipeline()` function I found that in this line ...

```
load_tokenizer = type(model_config) in TOKENIZER_MAPPING or model_config.tokenizer_class is not None
```

... `load_tokenizer` is set to `False` for `p1` because
`type(model_config)` is not found in `TOKENIZER_MAPPING` whereas load_tokenizer is `True` for `p2` because it was found. (See [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/c475eca9cd9aa0b5a88b269b6a090b645391267d/src/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py#L882) and [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/c475eca9cd9aa0b5a88b269b6a090b645391267d/src/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py#L473)).
I am not sure though if this finding is relevant as the `model_fn()` function in the model's `inference.py` does create a `tokenizer` by using `tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir)` and then passes it to `SummarizationPipeline`. I tired to create a tokenizer this way locally ...

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("/REDACTED/Code/infer-huggingface-summarization-bert-small2bert-small-finetuned-cnn-daily-mail-summarization")
```

print(str(type(tokenizer)))

... and I do get an instance of type `transformers.models.bert.tokenization_bert_fast.BertTokenizerFast`.

(I have to admit that I did not fully grasp everything that's going on here but continuing investigation...)

Comment: I tried the same code with another model `huggingface-translation-t5-small` and I could run the inference with payload `{"inputs":"some text..."}`. So it must be something specific to the model. After diving deeper into the code, I suspect that the cause has something to do with the way the tokenizer is created and that `self.tokenizer` is a string instead of a function. Therefore I get the error `str object <-- "i.e. tokenizer" not callable`. If I understand the code correctly, the tokenizer is derived from the model_id using AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained ... still investigating...

Comment: Is there an inference.py in your model.tar.gz? What are the contents there? Can you test and debug local model inference first to see if there's any issues.

Comment: Yes, there is an `inference.py` file in the tar.gz. 

Here's what I did: I used the function `list_jumpstart_models` from `sagemaker.jumpstart.notebook_utils` to find the model `huggingface-summarization-bert-small2bert-small-finetuned-cnn-daily-mail-summarization` which points me to the source_uri `s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-1/source-directory-tarballs/huggingface/inference/summarization/v1.1.0/sourcedir.tar.gz`. I downloaded the tarball and found the `inference.py`.

Comment: Sorry, to be more precise: The _model_ I am using is s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-1/huggingface-infer/infer-huggingface-summarization-bert-small2bert-small-finetuned-cnn-daily-mail-summarization.tar.gz When I download and unpack it, there is no `inference.py` in the tar.gz. Should there be one?

The other model s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-1/huggingface-infer/infer-huggingface-translation-t5-small.tar.gz I tried does work and the tar.gz does not contain an `inference.py` either.

Comment: I think I understand now. The sourcedir.tar.gz contains `inference.py` which defines a custom function for loading the model and tokenizer. But the model I am using, i.e. `infer-huggingface-...-summarization.tar.gz` does _not_ contain `code/inference.py`, hence, the custom code is not loaded and the ootb tokenizer and model loading mechanism is used instead. This ootb works for `infer-huggingface-translation-t5-small.tar.gz` but not for `infer-huggingface-...summarization.tar.gz`. I will test my hypothesis by copying the content of `sourcedir.tar.gz` into the model tar.gz and use this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**:
The problem was that my model tar.gz file (i.e. s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-1/huggingface-infer/infer-huggingface-summarization-bert-small2bert-small-finetuned-cnn-daily-mail-summarization.tar.gz) is missing the custom `inference.py` script, so the `sagemaker_huggingface_inferencen_toolkit` used the default `load()` function to load the module which failed to create an instance of the tokenizer and therefor failed calling the tokenizer, causing the error `str object is not callable`.

Here is what I did to fix the problem:

- I downloaded the model tar.gz file from S3
- I looked up the location of the corresponding `sourcedir.tar.gz` file by using a call to `sagemaker.script_uris` (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-jumpstart-models-and-algorithms-now-available-via-api)) and downloaded the `sourcedir.tar.gz`.
- I unpacked both, the model tar.gz and the `sourcedir.tar.gz` and moved the code from sourcedir into a sub-directory named `code` inside the model directory.
- I packed the model directory (now including a `code` subdirectory with `inference.py`) into a tar.gz and uploaded it into an S3 bucket.
- I used the URL to this new S3 bucket as my `ModelDataURL`.

**More details**:
Here are a few more details I discovered while debugging the issue. Both models tar.gz i used did not contain `inference.py` but one worked and the other did not. I tried to understand the call stack and why one failed and the other did not. I am sharing it here if you are a beginner (like me) and want to understand more what's going on.

1. The docker image specified in the SageMaker `Image` attribute uses the Python script specified in its ENTRYPOINT env var to start the `multi-model-server`. It does so by calling [`sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit.mms_model_server.start_model_server()`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-huggingface-inference-toolkit/blob/80634b30703e8e9525db8b7128b05f713f42f9dc/src/sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit/mms_model_server.py#L52). This function passes the `handler_service` to be used to the command line that starts the mms server. The mms server is installed in the docker image (/opt/conda/bin/multi-model-server).
2. The MMS loads the `sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit.handler_service` and calls its constructor `__init__()` function and then the `initialize()` function.

- The constructor uses `sagemaker_inference.Environment()` to set `environment.module_name` to default value `inference.py` unless otherwise specified in the `SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM` parameter. It also adds the `code_dir` (i.e. the `code` subdirectory of the `module-path`) to the `PYTHON_PATH_ENV` - which is important later.
- The `initialize()` function passes the `model-path` argument from the command line call to `multi-model-server` (see above, i.e. "/opt/ml/model") as the `model_dir` variable in the `context.system_properties`. Then `initialize()` calls [`self.validate_and_initialize_user_module()`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-huggingface-inference-toolkit/blob/80634b30703e8e9525db8b7128b05f713f42f9dc/src/sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit/handler_service.py#L80) which looks up the `module_name` in the loaded `sage_maker.environment`. If the `module_name` is specified (e.g. `"inference.py"`) **and can be found using [`importlib.utils.find_spec`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-huggingface-inference-toolkit/blob/80634b30703e8e9525db8b7128b05f713f42f9dc/src/sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit/handler_service.py#L274)** (therefore `code_dir` was added to `PYTHON_PATH_ENV` in the constructor) then it is imported and **overrides the default module loader `handler_service.load()` function**, the default transformer `handler_service_transform_fn()` and other handler_service functions with the ones specified in `inference.py`. See [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-huggingface-inference-toolkit/blob/80634b30703e8e9525db8b7128b05f713f42f9dc/src/sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit/handler_service.py#L274) and more background [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/inference#user-defined-code-and-modules).

3. Assuming the handler_service.load() function is NOT overridden by the module_fn function declared in `inference.py` (which was the case for me): The default `load()` function calls `transform_utils.get_pipeline(task=task, model_dir=model_dir, device=self.device)`. If `task` is already defined in the env var HF_TASK it is passed to `get_pipeline()`. Otherwise, `task` is loaded from the `config.json` file in the `model_dir` ("/opt/ml/model") by inspecting the `architecture` property and matching it against a dictionary. E.g., if the `architecture` is ending with `EncoderDecoderModel` then it is a text2text-generation task. In `transform_utils.get_pipeline()` function `kwargs[tokenizer]` is set to `model_dir` because task is "text2text-generation". Then the pipeline is created with the line of code
   (Note: `pipeline` is defined in `transformers.pipelines.__init__.py`.)

```py
hf_pipeline = pipeline(task=task, model=model_dir, device=device, **kwargs)
```

4. The function `pipeline()` tries to load the tokenizer by inspecting the model configuration from `"/opt/ml/model/config.json"`. It creates an instance of the right configuration class for the model type by using the `model_type` property in `config.json`. E.g. for a `t5` model type, it creates an instance of `T5Config` and for an `encoder-decoder` model type it creates an instance of `EncoderDecoderConfig`. It then checks what tokenizer to load by looking up the name of the tokenizer in the `TOKENIZER_MAPPING_NAMES` dict. It looks up the tokenizer by using the `model_type` from the `config.json` (there's a bit more magic in the lookup but that's essentially what it does) - see [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/c5c69096b385bb9782fcc01251f20956670b4497/src/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py#L882). **Now here is the key point: There is a tokenizer specified for `t5` but there is no tokenizer specified for the `encoder-decoder` model type.** Hence, `load_tokenizer` is `False` for the `encoder-decoder` model, and `tokenizer` remains a string (i.e. the module_dir path) in `pipeline()` instead of being actually loaded with a tokenizer. This is why my t5-based model `infer-huggingface-translation-t5-small` successfully created a tokenizer but the encoder-decoder-based model `infer-...-mail-summarization` did not. To finish call stack...
5. `pipeline()` infers the actual pipeline class from the `task`, e.g. for a `text2text-generation` task it returns an instance of `Text2TextGenerationPipeline`.
6. When I used the Pipeline of the encode-decoder model type (either by calling the model through the `handler_service.predict()` handler or the `handle()` handler ), the model called `preprocess()` and then `Text2TextGenerationPipeline._parse_and_tokenize()`. Inside `text2text-generation._parse_and_tokenize()` the **`tokenizer` was still a string** (see 4) and the call [`self.tokenizer(...)`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/c5c69096b385bb9782fcc01251f20956670b4497/src/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py#L132) failed because `tokenizer` it cannot be called as a function.

So, this is what was going on and why the lack of `code/inference.py` in the model's tar.gz file caused the error and I wrongly assumed it was due to the payload format.